# New PATH "Edit environment variable"

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables

On one of my Windows 10 computers, I get this new option for editing the PATH
variable:

> [image: path]

https://betanews.com/2015/11/23/windows-10-finally-adds-a-new-path-editor

However my other Window 10 computer just has the normal variable editor. Is this
only available for certain Windows editions? To respond to comment, this is
what I have on the other computer:

> [image]

After some more testing, it seems the new editor was available on both computers. However I accidentally deleted the PATH variable on one computer. Once I created the variable again, it no longer used the new editor. Is is possible to restore the new PATH editor?

Comment: Windows update?

Comment: So what versions of Windows 10 do you have installed? I am not asking which editions you have installed, if your using Home or Professional, isn’t relevant to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. If you delete the variable, then recreate like this:

```
C:\Sunday
```

it will maintain the old editor. But if you delete the variable, then recreate
like this:

```
C:\Sunday;C:\Monday
```

It will use the new editor.